# Qt error while loading shared libraries: __vdso_time: invalid mode for dlopen(): Invalid argument

Tags: c++, linux, qt, gcc, glibc

I packed a very easy Qt application (with shared libraries found by `ldd`) on my `debian 11`.

But it failed to run on ubuntu(20.04) virtual machine.

The error is : `error while loading shared libraries: __vdso_time: invalid mode for dlopen(): Invalid argument`

Both the glibc is version `2.31`.
 The version of qt is `6.3.2`.

I used to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to `.` or `/usr/local/lib`,it has no effect.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should *never* pack `GLIBC` or its constituent libraries (`libc.so.6`, `libm.so.6`, `librt.so.1`, `libdl.so.2`, `libpthread.so.0`) for reasons explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/851229/50617).

The most likely cause of the error is a mismatch between `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` and `./libdl.so.2`. Removing the 5 libraries listed above from this directory should make the application work.

Comment: I remvoed them.  And it does work now.